# How to continue writing the loop to the file and how to reset the initial value to 0 after each condition met?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

How do I write the file without repeating in the loop?
How to continue writing the loop to the file and how to reset the initial value to 0 after each condition met?

```
def main():
    infile=open("sales.txt","w")
    infilelist=[]
    #call function
    totalsale_each,salesperson=sales(infile,infilelist)

    for salesamount in infilelist:
        infile.write(salesamount)

    infile.close()


def sales(infile, infilelist):
    #set initial
    t_sales=0

    n_sales=int(input("Number of sales"))

    while t_sales<n_sales:

        #increasement
        t_sales+=1


        #for loop
        for s in range(1,n_sales+1):
            totalsale_each=0 #set the acc for total sales by each sales person


            sales_person=input("sales person name:")
            print("sales for sales no. "+str(s)+"by"+sales_person+":")
            infilelist.append(sales_person)               

            for count in range (1,5): #assuming one sales person can sell max and min of 5item per cust
                sales=float(input('sales#' +str(count)+ ':'))

                if sales<=300:
                    t_sales=t_sales+sales
                    totalsale_each=totalsale_each+sales

                if sales>300: #if sales>300, need to change the sales person
                              #that sales person needs to finish serving the rest of that cust's items
                    t_sales=t_sales+sales
                    sales_person=input("another sales pesron")
                    infilelist.append(sales_person)

                infilelist.append(str(totalsale_each)) #to write total sales for each person 
    return totalsale_each,sales_person

main()
```

This is my python test:

```
Number of sales: 2
sales person name:A
sales for sales no.1 by A:
sales#1:100
sales#2:150
sales#3:350
another sales pesronB
sales#4:200
sales person name:C
sales for sales no.2 by C:
sales#1:200
sales#2:500
another sales pesronD
sales#3:500
another sales pesronE
sales#4:200
```

The file I am getting after running is

```
 A
100.0
250.0
B
250.0
450.0
C
200.0
D
200.0
E
200.0
400.0
```

but what I want to get is like below:

```
A
600
B
200
C
700
D
500
E
200
```

How can I correct it?

I can't figure out where to put **infilelist.append(sales_person) and infilelist.append(totalsale_each)** after asking for the next sales person when sales exceed 300.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the indata too? Because it's hard to figure out what your code is supposed to be doing otherwise.

Comment: Very unclear, but at least you should unindent the line `infilelist.append(str(totalsale_each))`. Currently it is within the `for count in range(5)` loop which explains why you get several lines per sales person.

Comment: What is `sales_no = s*1` supposed to do?

Comment: How about the above edited one?

Comment: @Junuxx This is how I got from unindent the infilelist.append(str(totalsale_each))

`A
B
70.0
C
D
E
70.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when the sales go over 300, you want to write the total sales of that person, and ask for the next one.

So, what you need to do is, add the total of sales for each person, **after calculating the total sales**, which means after the loop in `range(5)`.

Also, you need to stop calculating sales after you find that a sales person has sold over 300. So, you need to `break` the loop at that moment, and continue normally.

The problem, here, is to go to the next sales person after that. Either you continue the loop and it will prompt as it would for any other name, OR you should ask for it in another form, and insert it in the array, and make sure it doesn't ask for another name like it would normally. The first option is simpler, if you need the second say so in the comment.

As a result, I would suggest these modifications to the `sales` function:

```
def sales(infile, infilelist):
    #set initial
    t_sales=0

    n_sales=int(input("Number of sales"))

    while t_sales<n_sales:

        #increasement
        t_sales+=1


        #for loop
        for s in range(1,n_sales+1):
            totalsale_each=0 #set the acc for total sales by each sales person

            # EDIT: this seems useless, so remove it
            #sales_no=s*1
            sales_person=input("sales person name:")
            print("sales for sales no."+str(s)+"by"+sales_person+":")
            infilelist.append(sales_person)               

            for count in range (5): #assuming one sales person can sell only 5item per cust
                sales=float(input('sales#' +str(count)+ ':'))

                if sales<=300:
                    t_sales=t_sales+sales
                    totalsale_each=totalsale_each+sales

                if sales>300: #if sales>300, need to change the sales person
                    t_sales=t_sales+sales
                    # write the last sales_person's total, and ask for another one
                    infilelist.append(str(totalsale_each))
                    sales_person=input("another sales pesron")
                    # add it to the list, after that, everything counts for him
                    infilelist.append(sales_person)
                    totalsale_each=sales
            # EDIT: decrease indentation so that the total is written once, after the loop
            infilelist.append(str(totalsale_each)) #to write total sales for each person 
    return totalsale_each,sales_person
```

**EDIT**: I edited the code: removed the `break`, write the last one's total, ask for another sales person, reset the total counter, and write everything in his name.

Also, a note about the return statement (maybe you already know that): it will return the last sales person's total sales and name.

However, I would suggest to rewrite the whole thing, so that you save the totals in a dictionary, with a key = the sales person's name or index (sales_no). After that, you write them all to the list.

**EDIT 2**: If you notice, after adding the new sales_person (`infilelist.append(sales_person)`), I am adding the sales to `totalsales_each`. It seems what you want is the opposite, so you should do this before adding the new sales person, which gives you:

```
if sales>300:
    t_sales=t_sales+sales
    totalsale_each += sales # the last sale counts for the last person
    infilelist.append(str(totalsale_each))

    sales_person=input("another sales pesron")
    infilelist.append(sales_person)
    totalsale_each = 0 # reset the sales for the next person
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestion but
if I use break, it wouldn't continue the inner loop

What I want to do is when sales>300, I want to ask for another person (e.g. like supervisor) because the inner `for count in range(5)` is the sales item for a customer so that another person need to finish serving the rest of that customer's items. So I need it to continue the loop.

Comment: So you want the loop to continue, but count in the supervisor's total?

Comment: Yes. Is there any solution to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the code
Why is the last sales for a sales person (i.e >300) not added to the first sales person?

e.g. `A, #1:100,#2:200,#3:500,Total:800;  B, #4:200, Total:200`
but when I run ur code:it is showing:
e.g. `A, #1:100, #2:200, #3:500, Total:300; B #4:200, Total:700`

Comment: This is normal, I thought this was what you want, I'll update and explain.